# How to handle the Set Similarity in Database

Tags: database, set, scalability, similarity, duplicate-data

I have an interesting problem. We receive the feed files from our customers which contains the products along with their information. We log each of the feed request received from our customers in a database.
The Problem is that given a feed file, we need to get all the feed requests which has the same list of products in the given feed file.Every feed request has nearly 2million candidate feeds for matching?

Answer (score 0):

Let me to summarize the probelem, just to make sure that we are on the same page.

The application may get a Feed Request, which contains list of products. Every time it happens, you log FR in db, and in addition you want to check for all FRs in the past which contained the same products set, is that right?

If so, an idea is to generate a hash key for a list of products within a FR. In that way every FR in db, has its own hash - which corresponds to list of products this FR contained.

Eg.

> Feed Request came to the app, and it contains products 2, 1, 3. The
>   app sorts products identities: [1, 2, 3], and then generate hash:
>   h([1, 2, 3]) = abc. Then, all you need to look for previous FRs with
>   the same products set, is to generate a query: "get all records from feed requests, where
>   hash is equal to "abc" ".

Such comparison is not very expensive if you index the data in the right way, even if there are milions of records.